# What does 'level' mean above sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**A level quayside area to which a ship may be moored to load and unload.**
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/wharf)

In the above sentence, What does 'level' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A level quayside area to which a ship may be moored to load and unload.

That's not a sentence, it's just a noun phrase (which makes sense because "wharf" is just a noun).

"Level" has its ordinary meaning: the same height at all places; parallel to a flat ground.

Basically, not sloping or irregular.